# How to have Bar subplots for a grouped data frame (by three columns)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a grouped data frame by three columns (Profession,Size and Gender) and I summed for the groups the column (duration). I would like to have separate subplots (barplot) for each `profession` and then have: the columns of each barplot as `Size` and the labels of each bar plot as `Gender`.
This is an example of my code:
In my full code I have around 30 professions so I wanted to loop over the subplots/profession but I don't know how to:

```
data = {'Profession':['Teacher', 'Banker', 'Teacher', 'Judge','lawyer','Teacher'], 'Gender':['Male','Male', 'Female', 'Male','Male','Female'],'Size':['M','M','L','S','S','M'],'Duration':['5','6','2','3','4','7']} 
data2={'Profession':['Doctor', 'Scientist', 'Scientist', 'Banker','Judge','Scientist'], 'Gender':['Male','Male', 'Female','Female','Male','Male'],'Size':['L','M','L','M','L','L'],'Duration':['1','2','9','10','1','17']} 
data3 = {'Profession':['Banker', 'Banker', 'Doctor', 'Doctor','lawyer','Teacher'], 'Gender':['Male','Male', 'Female', 'Female','Female','Male'],'Size':['S','M','S','M','L','S'],'Duration':['15','8','5','2','11','10']} 
data4={'Profession':['Judge', 'Judge', 'Scientist', 'Banker','Judge','Scientist'], 'Gender':['Female','Female', 'Female','Female','Female','Female'],'Size':['M','S','L','S','M','S'],'Duration':['1','2','9','10','1','17']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
 df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
 df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3) 
 df4=pd.DataFrame(data4)
 DATA=pd.concat([df,df2,df3,df4])
 DATA.groupby(['Profession','Size','Gender']).agg('sum')
```

The grouped table:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily with the `seaborn` package (see the [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) function)

```py
import seaborn as sns

# Make sure your `Duration` column is an int:
DATA.Duration = DATA.Duration.astype(int)

# Do the grouping
DATA = DATA.groupby(['Profession','Size','Gender']).sum()

# Make sure all your variables are in the columns:
DATA = DATA.reset_index()

# Plot
sns.catplot(data=DATA, kind='bar', col='Profession', 
            x='Size', y='Duration', hue='Gender')
```

Comment: Hi @Nakor, thanks for your answer . One additional question, how can I loop over the profession to have multiple subplots? (one subplot per a profession)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you already have 6 subplots (1 column per Profession). I also edited my answer to convert the duration to `int` since you define it as `str` in your example

Comment: yeah sorry it worked. :)  How can I change the size and the layout of the subplots... for the 30 professions, for example the subplots are on one row with no space between them. I would like to have 10 subplots per a row @Nakor

Comment: You can use the `col_wrap` argument. So col_wrap=10 will give you 10 columns max. For the size, you have the argument `height` and `aspect`, where aspect is the ratio of width over height. You also have the `size` argument to control the overall figure size